# look up the average value based on 2 categories and calculate

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClU4E.jpg)
I have data that will look up the average results of rows that fit the "X" category with the prefix of "id" with a data table like this

```
data
--------------------------              
X   |   id   |    value
--------------------------      
Mos |   1.1. |  74 | 78 | 70
Mos |   1.2. |  70 | 79 | 70
Mos |   2.1  |  70 | 76 | 73
Mos |   2.2  |  70 | 73 | 75
Mos |   3.1  |  77 | 72 | 78
Abs |   3.1  |  75 | 76 | 79
Abs |   3.2  |  74 | 80 | 77
Abs |   4.1  |  71 | 78 | 77
Abs |   4.2  |  76 | 76 | 76
Abs |   4.3  |  71 | 73 | 72
Cor |   1.2. |  75 | 70 | 78
Cor |   1.3. |  78 | 79 | 80
Cor |   2.1  |  79 | 70 | 70
Cor |   3.3  |  78 | 79 | 80
Cor |   4.1  |  78 | 74 | 72
Cor |   4.2  |  78 | 72 | 78
--------------------------
```

and the results as follows

```
result
------------------------            
id | Mos  | Abs  |  Cor
------------------------
1  | 73.5 | 0.0  |  76.7
2  | 72.8 | 0.0  |  73.0
3  | 75.7 | 76.8 |  79.0
4  | 0.0  | 74.4 |  75.3
```

how to make the formula?
Asume like this:

```
=IF("MOS" and LEFT(,1),SUM(D3:F4)/COUNT(D3:F4))
```

*if you find "MOS" in the "X" column, according to the "id" that starts with (1 or 2 or 3 or 4), then the value table will add up and divide.*

or

```
=AVERAGEIFS(D3:F18,B3:F18,I2,C3:F18,H3&"*")
```

Comment: Think you'll need an array formula of `=average(if(....` type.

Comment: i test in `=AVERAGEIFS(D3:F18,B3:F18,I2,C3:F18,H3&"*")` but result is `#VALUE`

Comment: Look closely, that's not what I suggested.

Comment: `=average(if(....`  will require a lot of columns in the result table.

Comment: Why...........?

Comment: hm ,, the results of the "X" column for 3 columns and "id" for 4 rows

Comment: `=AVERAGE(IF(AND(B3=I2,LEFT(C3,1)=H3),AVERAGE(D3:F3),""),IF(AND(B4=I2,LEFT(C4,1)=H3),AVERAGE(D4:F4),""))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a sample of your data, put this in H3 and copy down and across as necessary. An array formula so use Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

```
=AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$8=H$2,IF(VALUE(LEFT($B$2:$B$8,1))=$G3,$C$2:$E$8)))
```

[image]

Comment: ok its work. and i insert `IFERROR` like  `=IFERROR(AVERAGE(IF($A$2:$A$8=H$2,IF(VALUE(LEFT($B$2:$B$8,1))=$G3,$C$2:$E$8))),"")`. thanks @SJR

Comment: Yes, was going to suggest that actually.